# Find cells and copy the following cell to a separate worksheet

Tags: vba, excel, loops

I have an excel Workbook with several worksheets. Each of them contain value "N" in different places of the worksheet. I need to copy the value that is to the right from the value "N" to a separate worksheet. The copied values should be stored in worksheet as a column.

I assume that I need to loop through each worksheet, find address of "N" cell and copy/paste the cell which is to the right:

```
'Define last row and column

Function LastRow(sh As Worksheet)
    On Error Resume Next
    LastRow = sh.Cells.Find(What:="*", _
                            After:=sh.Range("B1"), _
                            LookAt:=xlPart, _
                            LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                            SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                            SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
                            MatchCase:=False).Row
    On Error GoTo 0
End Function

Function LastCol(sh As Worksheet)
    On Error Resume Next
    LastCol = sh.Cells.Find(What:="*", _
                            After:=sh.Range("B1"), _
                            LookAt:=xlPart, _
                            LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                            SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, _
                            SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
                            MatchCase:=False).Column
    On Error GoTo 0
End Function

Sub WorksheetLoop()

    ' Add a new summary worksheet

    Set DestSh = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Add
    DestSh.Name = "MergeSheet"

    Dim sh As Worksheet
    Dim DestSh As Worksheet
    Dim copyra As Range
    For Each sh In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
        Dim ra As Range
        'Find address of N in every Worksheet
        Set ra = sh.Cells.Find(What:="N", LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt _
                               :=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:= _
                               False, SearchFormat:=False)
        ' Find the address of the right cell
        copyra = ra + 1
        'Copy the cell to the MergeSheet
        copyra.Copy
        With DestSh.Cells(Last + 1, "B")
            .PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
            .PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats
            Application.CutCopyMode = False
        End With


    Next

End Sub
```

However, when I run this code it returns an error "Duplicate declaration in current scope" and it's not clear for me where I have the duplicate declarations.

Comment: Please use proper indentation, otherwise it's almost impossible to read. I've done it for you this time -- thanks to [RubberDuck](http://rubberduckvba.com/Indentation)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `Sub WorksheetLoop()`

This   `Dim DestSh As Worksheet` should go before `Set DestSh = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Add`

Use Option Explicit at the top of your code and you will also realise you have to declare

```
  Dim Last As Long
```

And that you have range variables that you later try to add things to that may cause type mismatches e.g.

You may want

```
Set copyra = ra.Offset(, 1)
```

Rather than

```
 copyra = ra + 1
```

Comment: Thanks for that! Still does not run through though; don't have time today anymore but will check tomorrow again and then get back to you (and also accept your answer if I get it to work...)

Comment: Thanks, that's very kind of you, highly appreciated! :)

Comment: I double checked my code and with the help of your comments and this code https://gist.github.com/ijd65/6075855 could fix mine. In the answer I post the script that I got

Answer (score 1):

I figured out how to solve the problem. Below there is the code for those who might need it

```
 Option Explicit

    'Define last row and column

    Function LastRow(sh As Worksheet)
        On Error Resume Next
        LastRow = sh.Cells.Find(What:="*", _
                                After:=sh.Range("B1"), _
                                Lookat:=xlPart, _
                                LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                                SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                                SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
                                MatchCase:=False).Row
        On Error GoTo 0
    End Function

    Function LastCol(sh As Worksheet)
        On Error Resume Next
        LastCol = sh.Cells.Find(What:="*", _
                                After:=sh.Range("B1"), _
                                Lookat:=xlPart, _
                                LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                                SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, _
                                SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
                                MatchCase:=False).Column
        On Error GoTo 0
    End Function

    Sub WorksheetLoop()

        ' Add a new summary worksheet

        Dim sh As Worksheet
        Dim DestSh As Worksheet
        Dim Last As Long
        Dim copyra As Range
        Dim ra As Range
        With Application
            .ScreenUpdating = False
            .EnableEvents = False
        End With


        Set DestSh = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Add
        DestSh.Name = "MergeSheet"



        For Each sh In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
            If sh.Name <> DestSh.Name Then

                ' Find the last row with data on the summary worksheet.
                Last = LastRow(DestSh)


                'Find address of N in every Worksheet
                Set ra = sh.Cells.Find(What:="N", LookIn:=xlFormulas, Lookat _
                                       :=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:= _
                                       False, SearchFormat:=False)
                ' Find the address of the right cell
                Set copyra = ra.Offset(, 1)
                'Copy the cell to the MergeSheet
                copyra.Copy

                With DestSh.Cells(Last + 1, "B")
                    .PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
                    .PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats
                    Application.CutCopyMode = False
                End With

            End If
        Next

    End Sub
```